# Extraction of year only instead of date in python

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Please can someone help with code to extract only the year and set it as a new column in data using python from the above photo attached here. when I try, the result shows no consistency, it gives me different values. it extract both the year and date instead of only the year. I think the year is the second character. I used different code and it isn't working.

I tried using this codes below

```
df_movies['correct_year'] = df_movies['released'].astype(str).str[-20:]

df_movies['years_scorrect'] = df_movies['released'].astype(str).str[:12]
```

Comment: Can you please specify the format of the date you are using or how does the string look like from where you're extracting the date?

Comment: This's how the date format looks like and want to extract just the year.                       August 15, 1980 (United States)
November 1980 (United Kingdom)
November 18, 1983 (Sweden)
September 9, 1980 (United States)
 . thanks for your reply.